# JQuery two autocomplete text-fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I don't know why if I have only one text field for categories the autocomplete is working (i can see suggested fill when user is typing in that categories text input box) but when I want to use more than one field let's say for subcategories it's not working on both (suggestions are not displaying)... Please help

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        $.getJSON(  {{ route('search.categories') }}, function( data ) {

            var categories = data.map(function(val){
                return val.title;
            });

            auto(categories);

        });
        $.getJSON( {{ route('search.subcategories') }}, function( data ) {

            var subcategories = data.map(function(val){
                return val.title;
            });

            auto(subcategories);

        });

        function auto(categories){

            $("#category_input").autocomplete({
                source: categories,
                minLength: 2
            });
        }
        function auto(subcategories){

            $("#subcategory_input").autocomplete({
                source: subcategories,
                minLength: 2
            });
        }




    </script>
```

View:

```
<input type="text" id="category_input" />
<input type="text" id="subcategory_input"/>
```

Comment: You cannot have two functions with the same name (`auto`). More specifically, the second one overwrites the first one.

Comment: @Jeto I thought "auto" is not a name but kind of a type like https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto

Comment: Well maybe in C++, but not in JS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $.getJSON(  {{ route('search.categories') }}, function( data ) {

        var categories = data.map(function(val){
            return val.title;
        });

        auto(categories);

    });
    $.getJSON( {{ route('search.subcategories') }}, function( data ) {

        var subcategories = data.map(function(val){
            return val.title;
        });

        auto_sub(subcategories);

    });

    function auto(categories){

        $("#category_input").autocomplete({
            source: categories,
            minLength: 2
        });
    }
    function auto_sub(subcategories){

        $("#subcategory_input").autocomplete({
            source: subcategories,
            minLength: 2
        });
    }




</script>
```

Comment: Thank you it's working but i had to delete ";" there       ` })

        auto(categories)`